# Sort list by chunks in python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of 2D points sorted by their x-coordinate. For example

```
l=[(1,2),(2,1),(4,2),(5,1),(6,7),(7,2)]
```

Now i want to sort this list by their y-coordinate but, let's say, only every three elements.

Which means

```
l=[(2,1),(1,2),(4,2),(5,1),(7,2),(6,7)]
```

I couldnt find something like this:

```
list.sort(startIndex,EndIndex, comparator)
```

Is something like this in python available or is there any elegant solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine sort and itertools.chain

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain
l=[(1,2),(2,1),(4,2),(5,1),(6,7),(7,2)]
list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(l[i:i+3], key=itemgetter(1)) for i in range(0, len(l), 3)))
```

Using list comprehension, you can even avoid using chain:

```
[x for y in (sorted(l[i:i+3], key=itemgetter(1)) for i in range(0, len(l), 3)) for x in y]
```

Comment: okay i will check this, is this also possible if i dont have tuples but an object which holds the tuple?

Comment: Yes the key can be anything that takes the object and return the comparable key, for example `key=lambda obj: obj.its_tuple[1]`